# Confluence plugin: How to export properly packages?

Tags: java, confluence, osgi-bundle

I'm developing my first confluence plugin. The plugin contains some macros which are using rest clients. During execution of the macro, some of my classes are not found with ClassNotFound exceptions.
The docu tellms me that i have to export my packages to make them "visible" to the OSGI bundle classloader.
According to docu this could be done either in atlassian-plugin.xml or on the pom file of the module.
My pom file has the following section:

```
  <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-confluence-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${amps.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
      <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
      <instructions>
        <Export-Package>
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib;version="${project.version}",
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.artifactstore;version="${project.version}",
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.macro;version="${project.version}",
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.nexus;version="${project.version}",
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.nexus.client;version="${project.version}",
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.nexus.config;version="${project.version}",
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.nexus.jaxb;version="${project.version}",
          info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.util;version="${project.version}"
        </Export-Package>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

(For the complete pom see http://pastebin.com/QSJajG8r)

When i check the MANIFEST.MF, it looks "correct", at least i see my exports (and imports have been added automatically), see http://pastebin.com/Gq2aKEYp.
(Well ... the format of the manifest is a bit weird ...)

However, i still encounter the ClassNotFound exception.

Can somebody please explain how exactly i must "export" my packages in a way that the OSGI class loader will find them?

Comment: There is the complete stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/Q4BLnE0y
It starts with 
Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface info.magnolia.confluence.plugin.mib.nexus.client.NexusRestClient is not visible from class loader

Comment: Don't export anything. Kill the entire `<Export-Package/>` section. If this is your first Confluence plugin, likely you won't need to export anything. Do without that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your dependency?

e.g.,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Regards,
Gorka